# Git: I get the non-fast forward updates message, but when I 'git pull' it says I am up-to-date?

Tags: git, github

In an existing project/repo, I created a new branch.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b 'my_new_branch'
```

I then did my work, which was just changing 1 line on 1 file. I then want to push this up to Github so I could create a pull request.

```
git add <file>
git commit -m 'made changes'
git push
```

But I then get the message

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

I'm assuming there's a merge conflict with that 1 file I changed, which is strange - I didn't think I would get merge errors as I wasn't 'merging' it, just pushing it up to Github so I could create a pull request.

Regardless, I ran

```
git pull
```

and

```
git merge origin/master
```

and no issues came up.

I'm not really sure what to do here. I've obviously Googled answers, but to be frank, I don't understand them.

Would someone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.

I think, somehow a `'my_new_branch'` branch was in remote before you did `git push` after checking out `'my_new_branch'` (git checkout -b 'my_new_branch'). And `remote 'my_new_branch'` had some new changes that was not in local 'my_new_branch'.

so, `git pull` followed by `git push` should work (it also worked for you here).

you can see log history to be confirm:

```
$ git checkout 'my_new_branch'
$ git log
# can you see any commits that came from remote
```

Comment: I did `git log` and I see there are a heap of merges, but they're from another completely differently named branch I did weeks ago. Really weird. Perhaps it's best to start again.